# MySQL Case Statements

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone here know the significant difference of single CASE statement with many WHEN against multiple CASE statements?

eg.

```
SELECT
  blah
  , CASE WHEN x THEN 'abc'
      WHEN y THEN 'deF'
      WHEN z THEN 'gHi'
    ELSE END

  , CASE WHEN x THEN 'abc' ELSE
      CASE WHEN y THEN 'deF' ELSE
        CASE WHEN z THEN 'gHi' ELSE
        END
      END
    END
```

.

Thanks in advance for the insights!

Comment: first one boils down to `if/then/else/else`. Second one is `if(if(if()))`

Comment: "ELSE END" is a syntax error at least under 5.0.  Omit the "ELSE" or say "ELSE NULL END".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not fully sure of what you want to hear but... Multiple `WHEN` clauses exist so you don't need to nest `CASE` statements.

**Edit:**

To clarify things: both constructs can do the same things, but nested CASEs makes code more messy and unreadable. A similar example:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(' ', 'A', CONCAT_WS(' ', 'B', CONCAT_WS(' ', 'C'))) AS nested,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', 'A', 'B', 'C') AS multiple
```

Comment: so, to use one or the other is essentially the same?

Answer (score 2):

From [How to Write Unmaintainable Code](http://thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html):

> **The Nested Switch**
>   (a switch within a switch) is the most difficult type of nesting for the human mind to unravel.

It's an opinion, for sure, but one I can't argue with. (Of course, `case` and `switch` are different syntax for the same logical construct.) Your second formulation is just unnecessarily nasty, so avoid it unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: Well happy days! Thanks all! This definitely clarifies the question I had in mind for a while now.